# Codeigniter Required parameter follows optional parameter problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello can you help me please?

Message: Required parameter $order follows optional parameter $where
Filename: models/Default_model.php
Line Number: 1

```
    public function get_all($tableName,$where = array(),$order)
{
    return $this->db->where($where)->order_by($order)->get($tableName)->result();
}
```

Comment: Optional parameters should be defined last. It doesn't make sense to have required after an optional since you can't "skip" a parameter when calling a function, at least if you're using a PHP version lower than PHP 8 when they introduced named arguments. Still doesn't make sense though.

Comment: How can I fix my code?

Comment: Either give `$order` a default value or change argument order to: `$tableName, $order, $where = []`

Comment: Let's look at this another way...What is your reason for setting the parameter $where = array()?

Answer (score 1):

Since $order is REQUIRED, and assuming you are always providing a $order then

```
public function get_all($tableName,$where = array(),$order='')
```

Will solve this ... HOWEVER, if there is a chance that you don't provide the order this will error out. So you have to change your code to be

```
if (!empty($order))
    return $this->db->where($where)->order_by($order)->get($tableName)->result();
else
    return $this->db->where($where)->get($tableName)->result();
```

Comment: So, could it be shorter?

return $this->db->where($where)->order_by(empty($order) ? "'title', 'DESC'" : $order)->get($tableName)->result();

Comment: Yikes! Yes that works but I always found Inline Ifs (?:) make it harder to debug down the line.  I am currently dealing with a bunch of code where the inline ifs are triple nested and the programmer didn't () them at all and php is really not liking it now.

Comment: okey, i understood :)

Comment: It it works mark this solved so that it goes green.